# Dynamic Virtual host - root folder based on domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, virtualhost

I have my virtualhost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
UseCanonicalName Off
VirtualDocumentRoot /home/xxx/www/%0
AssignUserID UserName xxx
<Directory /home/xxx/www/>
 Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride All
 Allow from all
 Require all granted
</Directory>
ServerAlias xxx.com *.xxx.com
php_admin_value open_basedir "/home/xxx/www:/home/xxx/tmp"
php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /home/xxx/tmp
php_admin_value session.save_path /home/xxx/tmp
ErrorLog /home/xxx/error.log
# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit, alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn
CustomLog /home/xxx/access.log combined
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</VirtualHost>
```

And I have web sites: www.xxx.com, preview1.xxx.com, preview2.xxx.com, preview3.xxx.com, somerandomsubdomain.xxx.com

Every domain and subdomain like www.xxx.com and previev1.xxx.com points to correct document root so I can add subdomains dynamicly.

Quiestion is: How can I easily make exception for preview3.xxx.com pointing not to /home/xxx/www/preview3.xxx.com but to /home/xxx/www/preview3.xxx.com/www?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create another VirtualHost in the same file, above the current one. Use the same configuration, just change these two values:

```
#VirtualDocumentRoot /home/xxx/www/%0
DocumentRoot /home/xxx/www/preview3.xxx.com/www

#ServerAlias xxx.com *.xxx.com
ServerName preview3.xxx.com
```